# Detect if an android contact has been deleted

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract, contentobserver

I am trying to maintain a contact database and get a callback for Add/Update/Delete as soon as something changes in the URI.

I have written a ContentObserver to observe on *ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI* on contacts. I get a callback as soon as a contact changes and then I update my database by checking *ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP*.
While this works fine for add/update, it does **does not work for deleting a contact**.

I do not want to parse all the contacts that I have in memory and check against android database. That would take time and CPU.

I know there exists many question of these types but I am not able to figure out things specific to deleting the contact.

Does there exist a way to perform this ?

Comment: Have u found any solution for it,i am going through the same

Comment: @user3475052 : android provides "ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI" for APIs 18 and above. You can use timestamp of this Content Uri to keep track of deleted contacts. This is much faster than keeping track of contacts via Contacts.Content_uri.

Comment: hey shreyansh can you plz explain a bit more

Answer (score 7):

As I have posted in above comment as well, following code works for API level 18 and above. 
You can query on a uri `ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI` to get the list of all the contacts that have been deleted.

My query looks like following :

```
    String selection = ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_DELETED_TIMESTAMP + " > ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(mLastContactDeleteTime)};
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Comment: what is mLastContactDeleteTime?

Comment: @ShReYaNsH  can you explain more please? what is `mLastContactDeleteTime`?

Comment: @Arik6 @HanWhiteking `mLastContactDeleteTime` is the time of last successful check, so you don't query a deleted contact twice.